# In MVC cross domain service call returning undefined function error, but able to see the json object in browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

calling an cross domain ajax call with jsonp, but returning undefined function error.

Service side:-
I have one WCF service which returning list of complex items. The function is decorated with

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/Menu/callBackFunctionName",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<MenuItem> GetMenu();
```

Client Side:-

From MVC view calling ajax function

```
   $.ajax({   type:     "GET",   
   url:      "https://abc.com/Menu",   
   dataType: "jsonp",   
   jsonCallback: function GetMenu(data){
   //alert statement 1
   },

   success: function(data){   // alert statement 2   }, 

   Error: function(){ // alert statement 3} 
});
```

Ajax call the function in the server side, but the response return is undefined, when we used chrome java developer tool json result is there, but function `GetMenu` is undefined error is showing.

showing  // alert 1

showing // alert 3

Please suggest how i can get response in field data and used in my view.

Answer (score 0):

You can open chrome using following code in **"RUN"** it will disable web security and this might solve your problem

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Comment: still getting the same error. Do i need to use WebApi for it.??

Comment: If you are working in chrome disable mode, now you don't need your dataType: "jsonp" even you can remove callback function. You can get data by doing simple ajax request.